# preg_replace doesn't match the correct group?

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a regex that will ignore (say):

```
<div> or <i> or <div class="something"> but will catch <divdiv> and <iii> or <hello>.
```

I was able to do it using:

```
<(?!\/)(?!(i|div)(\s|>))(.*?)>
```

But when I try to return the 3rd group (.*?), it doesn't seem to come back:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<(?!\/)(?!(i|div)(\s|>))(.*?)>/i", 
                            "< $3>",  // note I added space
                            $text);
```

I tried also using $1 and $2. Am I missing something?

**Update,** this is not at all clear to me.

I used the following

```
$text = preg_replace("/<(?!\/)(?!(i|div|p)(\s|>))(.*?)>/i", 
                        "< ${3}>",
                        $text);
```

On:

```
<p>test test test test annotation in <inline_code>power</inline_code>.</p>
```

According to https://regex101.com/ I should get:

```
<p>test test test test annotation in < inline_code>power</inline_code>.</p>
```

But when I run it on the server, I get

```
<p>test test test test annotation in power.</p>
```

Comment: double quote vs single quote?

Comment: I'm using php version 5.5.36

Comment: I tried on 5.5.9. Works.
${3} in double quotes will fail though, because php will try to interpret that as a variable expression before passing it to the function

Comment: This is baffling.  It's not a problem with the original code, which leaves what...? the validity of the data, differences in settings, ???

Comment: @TimMorton What's weird is that in the server output it's not just the backreference missing, but the entire replacement string.
So maybe there's a selective strip_tags() or something going on there.

Comment: @TalGalili I would like to post a new answer on this question, but I would like to clearly understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.  Can you please post 3 different sample inputs and what your expected output is for each after preg_replacing?  I look forward to helping you find a resolution. (definitely include your monkey-wrenching strings!)

Comment: Here a pattern that does the job without using any backreference at all: `$text = preg_replace('/<(?!\/)(?!(i|div|p)(\s|>))(?=.*?>)/i', '< ', $text);` Any success with that?

Comment: Hi Jay, your latest addition solved my problem, thanks! Please post it as an answer so that I could approve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on my console in every variation I have tried; single quotes, double quotes, copied directly from your post...

```
php > $pattern = '/<(?!\/)(?!(i|div)(\s|>))(.*?)>/';                            
php > $subject = '<div> or <i> or <div class="something"> but will catch <divdiv> and <iii> or <hello>.';
php > $text = preg_replace($pattern,
php ( "<$3 something>",
php ( $subject);
php > print $text;
<div> or <i> or <div class="something"> but will catch <divdiv something> and <iii something> or <hello something>.


php > $text = '<div> or <i> or <div class="something"> but will catch <divdiv> and <iii> or <hello>';
php > $text = preg_replace("/<(?!\/)(?!(i|div)(\s|>))(.*?)>/i", 
php (                             "< $3>",  // note I added space
php (                             $text);
php > print $text;
<div> or <i> or <div class="something"> but will catch < divdiv> and < iii> or < hello>
```

But your updated example has a problem:

```
php > $text = '<p>test test test test annotation in <inline_code>power</inline_code>.</p>';
php > $text = preg_replace("/<(?!\/)(?!(i|div|p)(\s|>))(.*?)>/i", 
php (                         "< ${3}>",
php (                         $text);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: 3 in php shell code on line 2
```

I am running PHP7

Comment: I think the **single** quotes around the **pattern** acutally made the difference. Otherwise it'd had to be \\s instead of \s etc.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've updated my question with now changing it to double quotes. I don't understand why this is not working...

Comment: I'd recommend using single quotes for both pattern and replacement and \3 rather than $3.
iirc old php can only handle the \ way.
Also it's what used at http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

Comment: Then again in preg_replace page it says $ is the preferred way and changelog is not mentioning it. I'm no help today, sorry :D

Comment: Did you notice the error message on your last try?  If not, I would change your error reporting to E_ALL.  I've seen high-rep SO people get pretty nasty about missing error messages.

Comment: At this point, I'm running out of ideas.  The only thing I can point to is the difference in PHP versions and perhaps what values php.ini has.

Comment: Wait, I *am* making an assumption about the data you're testing it on.  Pardon me for asking something so basic, but are you sure that you're testing the data you think you're testing?

Comment: Just for giggles, could you post your entire script so we can verify i